# Can I load an alternative controller based on some criteria?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

Often when testing or debugging, I insert blocks of code that is only executed for my IP:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="x.x.x.x") {
  // Do something special
}
```

Or I include a completely different file:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="x.x.x.x") {
  require "some-file.php";
}
else {
  require "some-other-file.php";
}
```

This allows me to test and debug without bothering other users.

Now, in a YII framework, I have replaced our payment gateway with another one, and thus I wish to load a different version of PaymentController.php only for my IP.

Is that possible at all in YII, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just test on a dev/test server? I may be missing something. The way we do it is to just bring up a dev server and then create a ssh tunnel to localhost and test away.

Another potential approach is to create a special Role called debug and use that if you must do this in production. That would allow you to apply the Role to your login, or perhaps a special debug login, and the Role controls access to this special test code.

Comment: Normally I would use a dev server, but the payment gateway uses callbacks to certain urls so I cannot simply call dev.example.com instead of example.com. Or rather, I did do that when developing and testing, but the final test with real credit cards instead of test cards should be done on the real server. At home I can simply change my hosts file to let the url point to the dev server, but the gateway can't do that of course. (Continued in next comment)

Comment: (Continued) It's not really a big deal as I can just switch in the changed file for a moment when testing, but I am also learning Yii and wanted to know if this was possible. I will take a look at the role approach.